# Line graph - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linegraph

I'm doing a line graph by using ChartJS. I couldn't retrieve the number of buyer and seller from member table in my database.

The [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPO5T.png) always showed the total row in member table based on this query, `SELECT  memberID, username, memberType, COUNT(memberID) AS 'count' FROM member`

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url : "../api/data.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var count = {
            B : [],
            S : []
        };

        var len = data.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (data[i].memberType == "B") {
                count.B.push(data[i].count);
            }
            else if (data[i].memberType == "S") {
                count.S.push(data[i].count);
            }
        }

        //get canvas
        var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");

        var data = {
            labels : ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JULY", "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "Buyer",
                    data : count.B,
                    backgroundColor : "blue",
                    borderColor : "lightblue",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                },
                {
                    label : "Seller",
                    data : count.S,
                    backgroundColor : "red",
                    borderColor : "lightred",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            title : {
                display : true,
                position : "top",
                text : "Line Graph",
                fontSize : 18,
                fontColor : "#111"
            },
            legend : {
                display : true,
                position : "bottom"
            }
        };

        var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
            type : "line",
            data : data,
            options : options
        } );

    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

});
```

How can I differentiate and display the number of buyer and seller based on the selected year and month? This is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I believe is that the "count.b" variable must be an array of records over time. That is, something like this:

```
var count = {
    B: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    S: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
};
```

If you have only a fixed number it understands that it is referring to the first month.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I differentiate and display the number of buyer and seller based on the selected year and month?